# multiple mysql queries in php

Tags: php, mysql, fetch

I am trying to get a specific square in a mysql table. Here is what I have so far.

```
$sql = "select Saturdaymorning From schedule where username like '%$user%';";
$stmt = $db->prepare("select Saturdaymorning From schedule where username like '%$user%';");
$stmt = $db->exec($sql)

$sql1 = "select Saturdayafternoon From schedule where username like '%$user%';";
$stmt1 = $db->prepare("select Saturdayafternoon From schedule where username like '%$user%';");
$stmt1 = $db->exec($sql1)
```

I am able to get the first one to work but the second gets a buffer error. How could one run multiple queries at once. I do not understand the "fetchall()" command or how it works. Thanks

[EDIT] I have to call them apart because I use them in if statements akin to

```
if($sql = "yes"){ satmorn = "Saturday Morning"}
```

and so on.

Comment: whats the use of havin it prepared when you just injected the variables directly in the statement, use them placeholders, then bind the values.

Comment: **Use Prepared Statements with binding parameters**

Comment: @Ghost how would I do this?

Comment: @MathMXC its already in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) there's an example of how to use [binding](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) including the fetch

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about PHP but I really don't see why you need to run multiple queries here when you are selecting from same table. You can modify your query to combine both statement be

```
select Saturdaymorning,
Saturdayafternoon
From schedule 
where username like '%$user%'
```